# How to have ESC also cancel CAPS if CAPS is enabled?

Tags: linux, vim, xorg, kde

Is there any way to configure the keyboard so that pressing `ESC` will also cancel the Capslock feature, if Capslock is enabled? I specifically use Kubuntu Linux with ESC and Caps keys switched (VIM user) but my coding SQL statements code practices dictate the use of CAPS for SQL keywords. I would prefer a general Linux / X solution but a KDE-specific solution is alright as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An X-Windows specific solution would be to use `xbindkeys`

1. Install `xbindkeys` from your distro's repository.
2. Create a config file `.xbindkeysrc` in your home directory
3. Run `xbindkeys -k` from the terminal. This should open a GUI window. With that window focused press the key you wish to bind.
4. Copy the code snippet relating to that key from the terminal
5. Paste it into your `.xbindkeysrc`
6. Replace the "command schema" with a command to run when you press that key.

In your case you would need to create a script to turn caps lock off and then generate a real escape key event (using `crikey` to send `XTest` signals perhaps)

You can check whether your caps-lock is on using `xset q | grep "LED mask"`

Comment: Thank you trideceth, that is a great answer. I don't see from casual googling that there exist either an `if` flow control in `xbindkeys`, nor a "Disable Capslock" code that would have no effect if Capslock is not set. I'll keep looking and update if I find either of those.

Comment: @dotancohen you would have to delegate to a bash script to do that

Comment: Thanks, I see your edit that even mentions how to do that. I'm fiddling with it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What about a dumb, short-sighted and brutal Vim-specific solution?

```
:s/\vfalse|null|true|access|add|as|asc|begin|by|check|cluster|column|compress|connect|current|cursor|decimal|default|desc|else|elsif|end|exception|exclusive|file|for|from|function|group|having|identified|if|immediate|increment|index|initial|into|is|level|loop|maxextents|mode|modify|nocompress|nowait|of|offline|on|online|start|successful|synonym|table|then|to|trigger|uid|unique|user|validate|values|view|whenever|where|with|option|order|pctfree|privileges|procedure|public|resource|return|row|rowlabel|rownum|rows|session|share|size|smallint|type|using|not|and|or|in|any|some|all|between|exists|like|escape|union|intersect|minus|prior|distinct|sysdate|out|alter|analyze|audit|comment|commit|create|delete|drop|execute|explain|grant|insert|lock|noaudit|rename|revoke|rollback|savepoint|select|set|truncate|update|boolean|char|character|date|float|integer|long|mlslabel|number|raw|rowid|varchar|varchar2|varray/\U\0/g
```

Comment: That might work! It's not finding anything as posted, I'll google how to get the regex to work and I'll post back. Thanks, Romain!

Comment: Forgot the `\v` at the beginning of the search pattern. It works, now. But it is very brutal and very dumb. `xbindkeys` sounds better.

Comment: Yes, it is too brutal and I've had to trim it down quite a bit. I'm now trying to get it to only match whole words but VIM regex is a bit different than PCRE. However, it is a great tool to have for the common one-liner SQL keywords such as `INSERT, INTO, TABLE, WHERE, SELECT, DELETE, FROM, LIMIT, ORDER, BY, ASC, DESC, SET, UPDATE`. As soon as I've got this whole-word issue sorted out I'm mapping it to leader-s. Thanks!

Comment: The following form is perfect: `:s/\v<where>|<select>|<delete>|<from>/\U\0/g`. Thanks! As is obvious, I will select trideceth's solution as it does answer the question and it much broader is scope. But I do love this trick and I see this becoming a common tool in my box. Thank you Romain!

Comment: De nada. Regular expressions are at the heart of Vim. It's sometimes a bit tricky to come up with the right pattern but once you have it it's so simple to create a mapping for later reuse… I ♥ Vim.

Comment: Changing that to a mapping was an exercise in experimentation. Here is the format, for those will will follow in my footsteps: `noremap <leader>s <Esc>:s/\v<select>\|<from>/\U\0/g`. Only the pipes need backslashes, in contrast to all the info that I was finding on Google which suggested that the `\`, `<` , and `>` characters should all be escaped. I wonder if that is due to my environment or other settings, though I don't see anything relevant.

Comment: If I understand your comment, you are refering to using `<foo>` vs `\<foo\>`. Am I right? That's because `\v` changes the meaning of a few characters in patterns. It's called "very magic" and you can read about it in `:h \v`. It's often used to reduce the number of backslashes.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had intended to google that later once I get some other issues taken care of.