# How to escape vim keywords in mappings?

Tags: vim

In [another thread](https://superuser.com/a/493253/93684) this terrific mapping was suggested as a way to upper-case SQL keywords:

```
noremap <leader>s <Esc>:s/\v<select>\|<from>\|<insert>\|<into>\|<table>\|<where>\|<delete>\|<limit>\|<order>\|<by>\|<asc>\|<desc>\|<set>\|<update>/\U\0/g<Return>
```

However, it appears that `<insert>` and `<delete>` are VIM keywords. How does one escape them? The obvious attempt to precede them with `\` does not work!

Thanks.

Comment: You could drop the "very magic" `\v` at the beginning and escape all the `<>` with backslashes.

Comment: Thank you, that ties in with the mention of "very magic" in the other thread. I also had to double up the `\` escape characters on the pipes as well. Please post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, escaping the angle brackets is probably the right way to go.

My original proposal used `\v` to reduce the number of backslashes in the search pattern but it didn't take into account the requirements of mapping.

The solution is thus to remove the `\v` and go into backslash frenzy to end up with something like:

```
nnoremap <F9> :s/\<insert\>\\|\<delete\>/\U\0<cr>
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case, since that occurs in a regular expression you can get around that problem by breaking up those sequences by using grouping to share the <> characters:

```
noremap <leader>s <Esc>:s/\v<(select\|from\|insert\|into\|table\|where\|delete\|limit\|order\|by\|asc\|desc\|set\|update)>/\U\0/g<Return>
```

More generally, you could replace the `<` characters (either all of them or just the ones before the problem words) with `<Char-0x3c>`, 0x3c being the ASCII value for the `<` character.

Comment: Very cool, thank you! There are so many ways to fry eggs with VIM!